# OpenCV Image frames not stabilizing

Tags: c++, opencv, video-capture, surf, homography

I am trying to perform a video stabilization technique using OpenCV and c++. This techniques involves the SURF detection and description, calculating homography and warping perspective based on the homography for each subsequent image frame. From the articles I have seen, I got the impression that this should produce a stabilized video but this is not the case. I can't seem to find out what I'm doing wrong. The following is my code

```
Mat prev_frame, curr_frame;
int minHessian = 400;
Ptr<SURF> detector = SURF::create( minHessian );
std::vector<KeyPoint> prev_keypoints, curr_keypoints;
Mat prev_descriptors, curr_descriptors;


VideoCapture cap("patio.mp4");

if (!cap.isOpened())
    return -1;

cap >> curr_frame;

detector->detectAndCompute( curr_frame, Mat(), curr_keypoints, curr_descriptors );

namedWindow("Original Video");
namedWindow("Modified Video");
moveWindow("Modified Video", 600, 0);

FlannBasedMatcher matcher;
std::vector< DMatch > matches;

for(;;){

    prev_frame = curr_frame.clone();
    prev_keypoints = curr_keypoints;
    prev_descriptors = curr_descriptors.clone();

    curr_keypoints.clear();
    curr_descriptors = Mat();
    cap >> curr_frame;

    if( !prev_frame.data || !curr_frame.data )
    { std::cout<< " --(!) Error reading images " << std::endl; return -1; }

    detector->detectAndCompute( curr_frame, Mat(), curr_keypoints, curr_descriptors );

    if (curr_keypoints.size() < 20) {
        continue;
    }

    matcher.match( prev_descriptors, curr_descriptors, matches );

    double max_dist = 0; double min_dist = 100;
    for( int i = 0; i < prev_descriptors.rows; i++ )
    {
        double dist = matches[i].distance;
        if( dist < min_dist ) min_dist = dist;
        if( dist > max_dist ) max_dist = dist;
    }

    std::vector< DMatch > good_matches;
    for( int i = 0; i < prev_descriptors.rows; i++ )
    {
        if( matches[i].distance < 3*min_dist )
        {
            good_matches.push_back( matches[i]);
        }
    }
    std::vector<Point2f> prev;
    std::vector<Point2f> curr;
    for( size_t i = 0; i < good_matches.size(); i++ )
    {
        //-- Get the keypoints from the good matches
        prev.push_back( prev_keypoints[ good_matches[i].queryIdx ].pt );
        curr.push_back( curr_keypoints[ good_matches[i].trainIdx ].pt );
    }

    if (prev.size() <=4 || curr.size() <=4){
        continue;
    }
    Mat H = findHomography( prev, curr, RANSAC );

    Mat modified;
    warpPerspective(curr_frame,modified,H,curr_frame.size());

    imshow("Original Video", curr_frame);
    imshow("Modified Video", modified);

    waitKey(30);
}
waitKey(0);
```

The original and modified videos are in the following links respectively:

https://www.dropbox.com/s/ilqwdocgankfe6n/input.mp4?dl=0

https://www.dropbox.com/s/1kd981j92drkfrn/output.mwv?dl=0

Please Help.

Comment: Please can you upload your video and share its link. It would help anyone to debug.

Comment: @saurabheights I have edited the post with the uploaded videos

Comment: Thanks. I have checked the videos. The processed video looked more turbulent, but I also noticed the black borders on the video frame. Also, your video has both global and local motion. Let me try out your code on my system and see what may be the issue. Give me a day.

Comment: @saurabheights just trying to wait patiently here.. :)

Comment: Hi, I had faced a little problem in compiling the code. Are you using Opencv3?

Comment: I got the code running. Will need to debug what's the issue. Its able to compute the Homography. P.S. apologies for late reply.

Comment: First, you have found trasformation matrix from previous to current. But then you are applying this matrix to current to get previous. Shouldn't you use inverse matrix. `cv::warpAffine(curr_frame, modified, H, curr_frame.size(), cv::INTER_NEAREST | cv::WARP_INVERSE_MAP, cv::BORDER_CONSTANT);`

Comment: @saurabheights still doesn't work

Comment: Got nothing as of now. I will try to debug later but can't promise. By the way, why are you using `prev_descriptors.rows` for finding good matches.